# Equivalent matrics

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $ (X,d) $ be a metric space and let $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function with the following properties:

(i) $ f(x)=0 $ iff $x=0$.

(ii) $ f(x)\leq f(y) $ if $ 0\leq x\leq y $.

(iii) $f(x+y)\leq f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in [0,\infty)$.

I want to show that $f\circ d:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is also a metric on $X$ equivalent to $d$.

I have shown that $f\circ d$ is a metric on $X$. To show equivalence I proceed as follows:

Let $G$ be open in $(X,d)$ and let $x\in G$. Then $\exists r>0$ such that $B^{d}_{r}(x)\subset G$. Let $y\in B^{f\circ d}_{f(r)}(x)$. This gives $f\circ d(x,y)<f(r)$. Thus $d(x,y)<r$ and so $y\in B^d_r(x)\subset G$. Therefore $B^{f\circ d}_{f(r)}(x)\subset G$, so, $G$ is open in $(X,f\circ d)$.

But I could not show if $G$ is open in $(X,f\circ d)$ then how it is open in $(X,d)$? How to use continuity of $f$? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be open in $(X, f\circ d)$ and $x\in G$. Then there is $r>0$ so that $B^{f\circ d}_r (x) \subset G$. That is, $y \in G$ whenever $f(d(x, y)) < r$. As $f$ is continuous and $f(0) = 0$, there is $\epsilon$ so that $f(t) < r$ whenever $0\le t < \epsilon$. In particular, whenever $d(x, y) < \epsilon$, we have

$$f(d(x, y)) < r$$

and so $B^d_\epsilon(x) \subset G$. Thus $G$ is open with respect to $d$.

(To my understanding, we do not say such two metrics as equivalent: instead it should be said that they generate the same topology.)

Comment: I am having a problem @John in continuity we choose $\delta $ corresponding to $\epsilon >0$ not converse.So how are u getting this?

Comment: @learnmore: There are some typos in the answer I just edited the answer.

Comment: Yes its all right now +1 @John

Answer (score 0):

Observe that since $f$ is continuous and monotone, it is a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (this is not hard to prove, though it still needs a proof). Then use the continuity of $f^{-1}$.